# How can I copy a table of data from a PDF file into Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, adobe-acrobat, copy-paste

I have a table of data and I need to get it into Excel.  I found a few websites that suggested copy and paste into MS Word and then use the "Convert Text to Table" which unfortunately doesn't work as the columns come in with a space in between them but if I choose space as the column separator it breaks up columns that have multiple words in them into different columns.

Is there a better recommended way to get a table from a PDF file into Excel?

Comment: Once you paste the data into MS Word, is there some kind of way to determine where each column is? In other words, you stated that some columns have multiple words with a space between them and that columns are separated with a space; by chance are there *two* spaces between columns or something similar in each row to show separation between the columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy table data from PDF to excel](https://superuser.com/questions/877688/how-to-copy-table-data-from-pdf-to-excel)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copy a table from pdf as a table?](https://superuser.com/questions/161535/copy-a-table-from-pdf-as-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing is much simpler than mentioned in the other answer.

In Acrobat/Reader, choose the Text Selection tool, and bring your table into full view.

Now press the Ctrl/Option key and select the table. You will notice that the cursor changes. When the selection is complete, you can copy and paste into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you VBA Code, this will Transpose the Copied Data Table from PDF to Excel.

Follow below written steps.

1. Copy Table Data from PDF file.
2. Paste in Excel sheet in a Column.
3. Run the VBA code.

Check the Screen Shot.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xLRow As Long
    Dim xNRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xOutRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String

    On Error Resume Next

    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select Data Range(only one column):", "Transpose to Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    Set xRg = Application.Intersect(xRg, xRg.Worksheet.UsedRange)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If (xRg.Columns.Count > 1) Or _
       (xRg.Areas.Count > 1) Then
        MsgBox "Used range only contain one column", , "Transpose to Excel"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set xOutRg = Application.InputBox("Select output range(specify one cell):", "Transpose to Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)

    If xOutRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set xOutRg = xOutRg.Range(1)

    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xLRow = xRg.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To xLRow Step 3
        xRg.Cells(i).Resize(3).Copy
        xOutRg.Offset(xNRow, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
        xNRow = xNRow + 1
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate

End Sub
```

**NB:** *The Data I've used to TEST the code has 3 Column(RED Colour Value), so that with For Loop Step & Resize value is 3. You change according to your Data structure.*

*Hope this help you.*